# Conditional Unique Counting in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to count the number of conflicts in my dataset by group. I feel like there has to be an easy way to do this in data.table, but can't seem to figure it out. I've created a dummy variable to tell me if there is a conflict for each row of the data.table:

```
testDT <- data.table(Name = c(rep('A',6),rep('B',5)),
                     Division = c(rep(11,6),rep(12,5)),
                     ID = c(205,205,NA,201,201,201,203,203,203,204,NA),
                     Conflict = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0))
```

I need to count the unique number of non-NA IDs that have a conflict flag of 1 and apply that count in a new column to each Name-Division grouping. This is what the answer should be:

```
testDT[, Count := c(rep(1,6),rep(2,5))]

    Name Division  ID Conflict Count
 1:    A       11 205        0     1
 2:    A       11 205        0     1
 3:    A       11  NA        0     1
 4:    A       11 201        1     1
 5:    A       11 201        1     1
 6:    A       11 201        1     1
 7:    B       12 203        1     2
 8:    B       12 203        1     2
 9:    B       12 203        1     2
10:    B       12 204        1     2
11:    B       12  NA        0     2
```

I've been thinking about some usage of `sum(!is.na(unique(ID)))`, but I'm not sure how to conditionally count the unique values without creating criteria in the i section of the data.table `(Conflict == 1)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can subset the `ID` variable by conditions within the data.table `[]` and then count the unique values:

```
library(data.table)
testDT[, Count := uniqueN(ID[!is.na(ID) & Conflict == 1]), by=.(Name, Division)]
testDT
#     Name Division  ID Conflict Count
#  1:    A       11 205        0     1
#  2:    A       11 205        0     1
#  3:    A       11  NA        0     1
#  4:    A       11 201        1     1
#  5:    A       11 201        1     1
#  6:    A       11 201        1     1
#  7:    B       12 203        1     2
#  8:    B       12 203        1     2
#  9:    B       12 203        1     2
# 10:    B       12 204        1     2
# 11:    B       12  NA        0     2
```

Or following your logic:

```
testDT[, Count := sum(!is.na(unique(ID[Conflict == 1]))), by=.(Name, Division)]
```

Comment: Why condition within `j`? I imagine it's slower. `testDT[!is.na(ID) & Conflict == 1, Count := uniqueN(ID), by = .(Name, Division)]` performs all the logical tests on the whole table, instead of doing the test on each group. Unless I'm missing something

Comment: Oh I see. This would assign `NA`s for those rows. Up to @shughes if that matters...

Comment: Oh, one other thing. `uniqueN` has an `na.rm` argument, so you can use that instead of conditioning on !is.na. Depending on what version you're on, that may hit you with a bug, though. (I had to update to get past it https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1771 )

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
testDT %>%
    group_by(Name, Division) %>% 
    mutate(Count = n_distinct(ID[!is.na(ID) & Conflict==1]))
#    Name Division    ID Conflict Count
#   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#1      A       11   205        0     1
#2      A       11   205        0     1
#3      A       11    NA        0     1
#4      A       11   201        1     1
#5      A       11   201        1     1
#6      A       11   201        1     1
#7      B       12   203        1     2
#8      B       12   203        1     2
#9      B       12   203        1     2
#10     B       12   204        1     2
#11     B       12    NA        0     2
```